# how can get the path from installer and how set in my app?

Tags: c#, installation, visual-studio-setup-proje, visual-studio-setup

i am writing a win app and now i want to make setup for my app,my code is:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Cu­rrentVersion\Run");
 rk.SetValue("MyAppName", @"C:\WhereMyAppIs\MyApp.exe");
```

now how can get the path from installer to set it???
thanks.

Comment: Hmmm. Why do you need to create Registry entries manually? Use Visual Studio to create a new "Setup Project"; it will automatically handle the nitty-gritty stuff involved in installing your application to the end user's computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio, you can right click on the setup project -> View -> Registry and then set the registry key you like.

Check out this sites:

[msi - Set InstallPath registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160173/set-installpath-registry-key-using-visual-studio-setup-project)

[Registry Settings Management (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4dsy50b.aspx)

Comment: i make registry key in this way "setup project -> View -> Registry and then set the registry key you like." but now how can set value when it become install?i mean i want to get path from user and then set .

Comment: sorry for very delayed answer! you can add a custom action which calls an exe-file that reads the path and put it into registry. go to Setup Project -> View -> Custom Actions -> select Install and Add Custom Action adding the exe-file.

Answer (score 0):

If it was installed using Windows Installer (.MSI files), you can use the [MsiGetComponentPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API:

```
    [DllImport("msi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int MsiGetComponentPath(string szProduct, string szComponent, StringBuilder lpPathBuf, ref int pcchBuf);
```

Call it like this:

```
int len = 256;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
MsiGetComponentPath(productCode, componentId, sb, ref len);
```

Comment: @Simon Mourier:i want to set the registry key when i install my setup file,but i don't know how can get the path from user and then set the value key of registry.

Comment: @na.farzane - are you using Windows installer?

Comment: @Simon Mourier:i use Visual studio.

Comment: @na.farzane - but with the "Setup & Deployment" project type?

Comment: @Simon Mourier:yes with "Setup & Deployment".

Comment: @na.farzane - so where are you going to execute the code you show in the original question?

Comment: @Simon Mourier:i don't know,where can i write that when i install the setup file the registry become set with the value????

Comment: @na.farzane - Maybe you don't need to write any code. What about TeamPlayer answer? Why doesn't it answer the question?