# MSI to add registry key for x86 and x64

Tags: registry, windows-installer

I'm creating a MSI and need to write to the registry ([I use a URI Schema for hyperlinks to open the program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)).

The problem I have is writing the registry key for x86 and x64.

On 64 bit PCs the application will be installed to c:\Program Files (x86)\

[image]

On 32 bit PCs to c:\Program Files.

[image]

Ideally I was hoping to use a Environment Variable that would work on both PCs. eg:

"%programfiles%\MyFolder\MyApp.exe" %1

Does anyone know the method to write the registry key in the MSI so the file path works for both Operating Systems?

Answer (score 1):

I've already done this before:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11490003/495455

I forgot to use [TARGETDIR].