# Windows Form Application Deployment Using Setup Installer

Tags: c#

I have made a setup installer of my windows form application. Everything is working fine.I am facing the problem that How can i add  application updates  which is already installed at different client systems? Any guidence will be much appreciated.Thanks I have tried ClickOnce Deployment but it wont make effect on setup installer.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11490003/495455

Comment: Can you be more specific about your setup installer? There's more than one kind.

Comment: Hi, so your 'setup installer' is a ClickOnce installer? Or are you using something else like WiX, InstallShield, NSIS?

Comment: Made a setup installer of my windows form App. I sent this installer to the client . Now there are some updates in the App. How can i update the application now?

Comment: SetUp Installer is .msi file