# How can I create a setup project for a .NET 6 / C# Windows Forms project?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I created a project with C# Windows Forms running on .NET 6.0.

I want to distribute the installation file using a Setup project. But I don't know what to choose from [Prerequisites...].

- .NET Desktop Runtime?
- .NET Runtime?
- Microsoft .NET Framework?

  - (x64)?
  - (x86)?

What should I choose?

Comment: Here's instructions, they're a bit old but it should be roughly the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474320/install-to-same-path-when-upgrading-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a setup for your application in Visual Studio then follow the steps below to do it

1. Add a new Setup project to your solution by right clicking on the solution then click on **Add** then **New Project** from the sub context menu.
2. Search for a **Windows Application Packaging Project** template and click **Next**
3. Specify a name for the project and and hit **Create**, you may see a prompt for the minimum Windows platform versions that your application will support, specify accordingly.
4. After the setup project is created in Visual Studio then **right click** on it and choose **Add** and then **Project Reference** from the sub context menu
5. In the window that shows up, choose your project that you created first by checking on the box next to its name and hit **OK**
6. To generate a setup for the application, simply right click on the Setup project and hit **Build**
7. The setup file will be generated in the output path configuration specified in setup project